# In C, How to get full timestamp (even after seconds) in linux?

Tags: c, linux, operating-system, unix-timestamp, timestamp-with-timezone

I get a stream of bytes, after each 2000 bytes, I want to create a new file and store it. as it is a continuous stream of bytes, I cant use counter etc. 
So, I want to use system time stamp to identify file uniquely like `filename`.

I found some threads to get system time stamp, but there I am seeing till seconds. Is there any other way, with which we can get full timestamp in C, linux OS (`timestmap like: 2011-11-08 18:02:08.954092000`)?
In all thread, I am seeing only till seconds like `2011-11-08 18:02:08`

Comment: Using a timestamp, regardless of precision, may still collide.  Use `tmpnam()`. to "generates a string that is a valid file name and that is not the same as the name of an existing file"  Also `tmpfile_s()`

Comment: Note that, in Linux, an 'inode' is 4k and each file data block is 4k.   So making a bunch of 2k byte files is extremely wasteful of the disk space.  suggest: save to a new file in 4096 byte chunks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Linux has [`clock_gettime()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/clock_gettime) with nanosecond resolution.

Example code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>

int main(void) {
    unsigned mult = 0;
    struct timespec t0, t1;
    clock_gettime(CLOCK_REALTIME, &t0);
    for (unsigned k = 0; k < 10000000; k++) mult *= k; // no overflow!
    clock_gettime(CLOCK_REALTIME, &t1);

    printf("%lld.%09ld --> %lld.%09ld\n",
          (long long)t0.tv_sec, t0.tv_nsec,
          (long long)t1.tv_sec, t1.tv_nsec);
    return 0;
}
```

On my machine (FreeBSD/Unix but should be the same as any Linux), the code above prints

```
1438167485.022409606 --> 1438167485.055779608
```

Answer (score 1):

Example code to create a filename string with millisecond timestamp:

> get_time_in_ms.c

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<math.h>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<time.h>

void get_time_in_ms()
{
    long ms;
    time_t time;
    struct timespec spec;
    char filename[14];

    clock_gettime(CLOCK_REALTIME, &spec);

    time  = spec.tv_sec;
    ms = round(spec.tv_nsec / 1000000 ); // Convert nanoseconds to milliseconds

    printf("Current time: %lu.%03ld seconds since the Epoch\n", time, ms);
    sprintf(filename,"%lu%03ld",time, ms);
    printf("File name : %s\n", filename);
}

void main() {
        get_time_in_ms();
}
```

Output:

```
$ gcc -Wl,--no-as-needed -lrt -lm get_time_in_ms.c -o get_time_in_ms
$ date && get_time_in_ms

Wed Jul 29 16:51:20 IST 2015

Current time: 1438168880.503 seconds since the Epoch

File name : 1438168880503
```

Comment: Concerning `sprintf(filename,"%lu",time);`, Does `Linux specify `time_t` to be a `unsigned long`?

Comment: @chux: [the Standard says](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.27.1) that `time_t` (and `clock_t`) *"are real types capable of representing times"*. [POSIX extends the Standard](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/sys_types.h.html) with *"clock_t shall be an integer or real-floating type. [CX] [Option Start] time_t shall be an integer type. [Option End]"*. **Anyway ... a conversion is required to print it** `printf("%lu", (unsigned long)time);`

Answer (score 0):

Use `date --rfc-3339='ns'` command to see the o/p in nanoseconds precision. You can try looking `"man date"` command for finer details. As you can see, following is the o/p I get with this command:

```
[user1@mach]# date --rfc-3339='ns'
2015-07-29 03:34:09.077024060-07:00
```